# jQuery DataTables filter rows based on multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to have multiple filters that will hide/show rows on my datatable based on which filters are selected. My plan is to place the filter values in an array and compare those to the data-search attribute in the first column, but what  I currently have does not work.

Here's a JSfiddle that I have plus code below
https://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/06j4pxjk/3/

**HTML with checkboxes for filters and the table data..**

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="cat" class="filter"> Cats
</label>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="dog" value="dog" class="filter"> Dogs
</label>

<table class="select_items">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Crest Allowed</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-search="cat">1</td>
            <td>Testing Bowl</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td><button class="button">Select</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-search="dog">32</td>
            <td>Cup Test</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td><button class="button">Select</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-search="dog">3335</td>
            <td>Bowl Test</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td><button class="button">Select</button></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**The JS..**

```
var select_items = $('.select_items').DataTable();

var filters = [];

$('input.filter').on('change', function(){
   var filters = [];
   $("input.filter:checked").each(function(){

    var checkedBox = $(this).val();
    if (filters.indexOf(checkedBox) === -1){
        filters.push(checkedBox);
    }
   });

   console.log(filters);

   if(this.checked){
      $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
         function (settings, data, dataIndex){
            return (data[0].indexOf(filters) > -1) ? true : false;
         }
      );
   } 

   select_items.draw();

   if(this.checked){
      $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();    
   }
});
```

Comment: It works for me https://jsfiddle.net/06j4pxjk/2/

Comment: Not quite. When I have both selected I get no results.. I should see all 3 rows. Also if I select both then unselect Dogs I still see all 3 when I should just see the first row.

Comment: You want the filters to act like an `or` instead of an `and`?

Comment: Yes so if somebody selects cat and dog it will show rows that have either cat or dog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes in your code, using the `fnFilter` API:

> Documentation: https://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.0/DataTable.html#fnFilter

```
$(function() {
  otable = $('.select_items').dataTable();
})

function filterme() {
  //build a regex filter string with an or(|) condition
  var types = $('input:checkbox[name="filter"]:checked').map(function() {
    return '^' + this.value + '\$';
  }).get().join('|');
  //filter in column 0, with an regex, no smart filtering, no inputbox,not case sensitive
  otable.fnFilter(types, 0, true, false, false, false);  
}
```

You can see it working here: <kbd>[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/06j4pxjk/6/)</kbd>

Comment: This is great.. but any idea why this doesn't work when wrapped in dom ready?

Comment: Nevermind.. I see there's a difference between dataTable() and DataTable(). I'll have to do some reading on that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to make this work across multiple columns? I have some data in column 2 that I'd like to filter by as well.

Comment: You can create another question with more detail and add the link as a comment here...I'll take a look :)

Comment: No problem.. here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229250/datatables-how-to-filter-across-multiple-columns

Answer (score 3):

Considering, accepted answer refers to legacy interface `fnFilter` and, as of DataTables 1.10 new API is suggested, I'll allow myself to provide more up to date solution, which is, in my opinion, way more scalable, neat and simple:

```js
//define statical data
var srcData = [
  {search: 'Cat', item: '1', descr: 'Testing Bowl', crest: 'NO'},
  {search: 'Dog', item: '32', descr: 'Cup Test', crest: 'NO'},
  {search: 'Dog', item: '3335', descr: 'Bowl Test', crest: 'NO'},
];
//define dataTable object
var dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {title: 'Item', data: 'item'},
    {title: 'Description', data: 'descr'},
    {title: 'Crest Allowed', data: 'crest'},
  ]
});
//put in place dynamically created checkboxes
var searchValues = [];
dataTable.data().sort().toArray().forEach(row => {
  if(searchValues.indexOf(row.search)==-1) searchValues.push(row.search);
});
var checkboxes = searchValues.reduce((html, item) => html += `<input type="checkbox" value="${item}" class="filter">${item}</input>`,'');
$(checkboxes).insertBefore($('#mytable'));
//employ $.fn.DataTable.ext.search
var lookupValues = [];
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((settings, row, index, rowObj) => lookupValues.indexOf(rowObj.search) > -1 || lookupValues.length == 0);
//watch checkboxes and redraw table on change accordingly
$(".filter").on('change', () => {
  lookupValues = [...$('.filter:checked')].map(checkbox => $(checkbox).val());
  dataTable.draw();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for the `filter` length.

If there is no `filter`, the `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push` function has to return `true` for ALL rows.

And, I think that `search.pop()` should apply on uncheck too...

```
var select_items = $('.select_items').DataTable();


$('input.filter').on('change', function(){
  var filters = [];
  $("input.filter:checked").each(function(){
    var checkedBox = $(this).val();
    if (filters.indexOf(checkedBox) === -1){
      filters.push(checkedBox);
    }
  });

  console.log(filters.length);

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex){
    if(filters.length>0){
      return (data[0].indexOf(filters) > -1) ? true : false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  });

  select_items.draw();
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/j50d5m1r/)