# DataTables - how to filter across multiple columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'd like to be able to filter by multiple columns using DataTables. Right now I'm using fnFilter() to filter, but its column parameter seems to only accept a single integer, not an array of columns. This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/x85o0mgL/2/

In the "crest allowed" column I have a `data-search` attribute with either `yescrest` or `nocrest` set. I'd like to use the "Crest" checkbox to be able to filter by that as well.

If I click the Pristine and Crest checkboxes I should see the two pristine items that allow crests.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In other words,  the question should be self-contained and not rely on external resources like a jsFiddle. This allows it to be helpful for a long time to come (fiddles are good though)

Comment: Hi Dustin, how are you?....maybe is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/x85o0mgL/3/

Answer (score 1):

You may check out [this](https://github.com/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter) DataTables plug-in, which allows multiple-column-multiple-criteria filtering (including union selection).

Here is the working **DEMO**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 //Source data definition 
 var tableData = [
    {item: 'banana', category: 'fruit', color: 'yellow'},
    {item: 'pear', category: 'fruit', color: 'green'},
    {item: 'cabbage', category: 'vegie', color: 'green'},
    {item: 'carrot', category: 'vegie', color: 'red'},
    {item: 'apple', category: 'fruit', color: 'red'},
    {item: 'kiwi', category: 'fruit', color: 'brown'}
 ];
 //DataTable definition 
 window.dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
   sDom: 'tF',
   data: tableData,
   columns: [{
     data: 'item',
     title: 'Item'
    }, {
     data: 'category',
     title: 'Category'
    }, {
     data: 'color',
     title: 'Color'
  
   }]
 });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.mfilter.tk/js/mfilter.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.mfilter.tk/css/mfilter.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting but your example probably doesn't work properly, there are no column filtering elements.

Comment: Click filter icon

Comment: There is no filter icon, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyJOf.png).

Comment: +1 for the answer. is it possible to get only filter option ? i don't want to force user click on filter, cancel etc

Comment: also how do i generalized it ? it's binded to these headers and would it work when render data dynamically. I have 100s of tables with different columns. writing JS functions for every table to not good idea i believe