# How to pass multiple filters to jQuery datatable?

Tags: datatables

- I have a jQuery dataTable which I use to search for a month like this:

```
    table.column(1).search("February").draw();
```

- I would like to pass 2 months as filter now but this does not work:

```
    table.column(1).search(["Ferbrary", "March"]).draw();
```

- Also, `search` returns an `DataTables.API` object as per the documentation - https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

Is there anyway we can add 2 DataTables.API objects and invoke a `draw()` on the combination? I tried this and it didn't work:

```
    filtered_table = table.column(1).search("February") + table.column(1).search("March");
    filtered_table.draw();
```

- This link [jQuery DataTables filter rows based on multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212233/jquery-datatables-filter-rows-based-on-multiple-values) says we can use a different function `fnFilter` instead of `search` to search multiple values using regex.

As per the suggestion in the above link, I tried these and none worked:

```
    table.fnFilter("^February\$|^March\$", 1, true, false, false, false).draw();
```

```
    table.fnFilter("February|March", 1, true, false, false, false).draw();
```

How do I achieve multiple value filters on the same column? Pls help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions with [`column().search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()) API method to search for multiple values in the same column.

For example:

```
table.column(1).search('February|March', true, false).draw();
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/rt0qocp7/) for code and demonstration.