# display only specific rows in DataTables

Tags: jquery, django-rest-framework, datatables

I would like to display only a specific set of rows in JQuery Datatables based on some conditions (the query/URL of the page).

I am using REST API to pass the data in AJAX. Here is my full example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //datatables
    $('#mytable').DataTable({
      "ajax": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/example/?format=datatables",

     "serverSide": true,
     "processing": true,

      "columns": [
          {"data": "col1"},
          {"data": "col2"},
          {"data": "col3"},
      ],

      "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>>" +
             "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
             "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-4'p>>",
    });
} );
```

I would like to display only a subset of the rows based on some condition over col1 for example.

Is there a way to specify the rows like we specify the columns?

Comment: It would make the most sense to filter the data on the server side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery DataTables filter rows based on multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212233/jquery-datatables-filter-rows-based-on-multiple-values)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes server-side filtering with Django worked. Thanks for your help. Please add your answer so that I can close the question if this is not too trivial.

Comment: To be honest I don't feel that I answered your question as it was just a suggestion of how to best approach the problem. If you'd like you could add your own answer showing the code you used - which is perfectly acceptible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RoryMcCrossan suggested the answer is to filter server-side.
Since I am using Django, the filtering can be done in the `views.py`.

The page rendering can be done as follows based on some condition:

```
def page(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    items=items.filter(col1="somecondition")
    return render(request, 'page.html', {'items': items})
```

In this case, the datatable is not called from REST API anymore but directly in the template from the model as described in `models.py`